# Setting parent form/window for 2 processes in C#/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

Process M shows the main form (WPF). Process M starts another process D. Process D shows a dialog (WPF). Is there a way to let the main form be the parent of the dialog? The processes have different bitness on 64 bit OS.

I'd not like to use TopMost flags, because I don't want the dialog to be in front of everything, just in front of my main form.

I can implement some data exchange between those processes, so basically everything is possible, e.g. transferring the window handle to the other process or similar. PInvoke() or unsafe code is also ok for me.

The proposal should work on Vista SP2 and higher. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say no as there is a clear statement that a View can only be accessed by the thread that created it.

So windows created by different threads cannot be related, sorry.

Check this document: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx (the section multiple windows, multiple threads).

Comment: Well, I thought as long as such things exist: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/changov/archive/2009/10/26/hosting-wpf-ui-cross-thread-and-cross-process.aspx, it cannot be too much of a problem setting the parent of a window.

Comment: It is not the same thing to host a UserControl inside a View that setting one window as the parent of another one. The first interaction does not require 'cross-thread' functionalities while the second one does.